# Ruby on Rails - Querying Active Record Model With has_many Association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, associations, has-many

I am creating a RESTful API endpoint to return a given user a set of locations that are both public and private.  I have a model named `Location` that has an `owner_id` and a `location_type` field.  The `owner_id` links the `Location` to a user that owns it, and the `location_type` defines the type of location which can be either a contact, business or brand.  Locations of type business or brand are visible to all users, while contacts are only visible to the users that own them.  Currently I use the following code to retrieve all locations for a given user:

```
@locations = Location.where("location_type IN ('business', 'brand') OR
                 (location_type = 'contact' AND owner_id = ?)", params[:id])
                  .order(created_at: :desc)
```

This code performs as expected returning all public locations (business or brand), and all private locations for that user (contacts owned by that user).

The problem arises when I removed the `owner_id` from the `Location` model and created a separate model, `LocationOwner`.  `LocationOwner` `belongs_to` `Location` and is connected through a `has_many` association.  This was done so that each location of type contact could have additional owners added to it when a contact was shared with another user.

How can I modify the above code to query for all locations of type `business` and `brand`, and all locations of type `contact` that have a `LocationOwner` that is equal to the user id provided by the `params[:id]`?  Is this possible to do in one query? Am I going to have to use two queries as I am now querying two different tables, or does the `has_many` association take care of it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can join the tables on the `LocationOwner`'s foreign key to the `Location` (assuming that table has a `location_id` or equivalent). In this case, since business- or brand-type locations won't have corresponding rows in the `LocationOwner` table that point to them, you can use a left outer join that ensures all locations remain included. Try this:

```
Location.joins("LEFT OUTER JOIN location_owners ON locations.id = location_owners.location_id")
        .where("location_type IN ('business', 'brand') OR (location_owners.id = ?)", params[:id])
        .order(created_at: :desc)
```

Comment: Hey man, that seemed to have worked!  I made one small change to your solution so that it would work with the project I am using, but other then that everything else was spot on.  Thanks @Jake Shorty